# Reporting Services Hyperlink not works in VB 6

Tags: reporting-services, vb6

I have Reports created in Reporting Service 2008, the reports are allowed in a report server.

One report has Hyperlink Text that called the others reports.

I have a .NET Application which load the reports successfully and the Hyperlinks work, the application is created in Visual Studio 2012. I have other application created in Visual Basic 6, this application has a DLL which called the same reports, but the hyperlink is not working.

Comment: Is the hyperlink just text or did you set it up as `Textbox Properties...`-`Action`-`Go to URL`?

Comment: Only a Text with Action to other report, in .net application working, appears the link, but only in VB 6 application not workinga and not appears the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the dll wich is bulding in interopforms v2.0 the solution is v2.1